# Как вывести информацию в виде таблицы в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет, не могу вывести информацию в виде таблицы. Пробовал с помощью пандас ну у меня не получилось

файл customer.py

```
import Person

class Customer(Person.Person):
    def __init__(self, name, address, telephone, email, mail, number): #fixed number of arguments to pass for class instantiation 
        super(type(self), self).__init__(name, address, telephone, email) #Also here and not the use of `super`
        #super().__init__(name, address, telephone, email) with Python 3+
        self.mailing = True if mail == 'Y' else False #Fixed self.mailing expression
        self.__mail = mail
        self.__number = number

    def set_mail(self, mail):
       self.__mail = mail

    def set_number(self, number):
        self.__number = number

    def get_mail(self):
        return self.__mail

    def get_number(self):
        return self.__number

    def mailList(self): 
        if self.mailing == True: 
            return "On the mailing list"
        else:
            return "Not on the mailing list"

    def __str__(self):
        return "\nName: {}\nAddress: {}\ntelephone: {}\nEmail: {}\nMail: {}\nNumber: {}".\
                format(self.get_name(), self.get_address(),\
                       self.get_telephone(), self.get_email()\
                       , self.mailList(),self.get_number())
def main():

    customer = Customer('Josh', 'Long st, Dallas TX',\
                                 '555-987-1549','adsf@asd.com','Y','1153')
    customer1 = Customer('Djon', 'Long st, Dallas TX',\
                                 '555-987-1549','adsf@asd.com','Y','1153')
    customer2 = Customer('Ser', 'Long st, Dallas TX',\
                                 '555-987-1549','adsf@asd.com','Y','1153')
    print(customer)
    print(customer1)
    print(customer2)

main()
```

файл person.py

```
class Person(object):#only change
    def __init__(self, name, address, telephone, email):
        self.__name = name
        self.__address = address
        self.__telephone = telephone
        self.__email = email

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_address(self, address):
        self.__address = address

    def set_telephone(self, telephone):
        self.__telephone = telephone

    def set_email(self, email):
        self.__email = email

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_address(self):
        return self.__address

    def get_telephone(self):
        return self.__telephone

    def get_email(self):
        return self.__email
```

Сейчас выводит информацию так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно сделать чтобы информация выводилась вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Вам нужно как html вывести? Или в картинку?

Comment: @gil9red мне нужно его вывести в IDLE и все, как обычным выводом через print()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предлагаю [простенький вариант ascii-таблицы](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/76bb4cfa139ff14c319f836f4cf78985608b2bc8/ascii_table__simple_pretty__rjust.py):

```
def print_pretty_table(data, cell_sep=' | ', header_separator=True):
    rows = len(data)
    cols = len(data[0])

    col_width = []
    for col in range(cols):
        columns = [data[row][col] for row in range(rows)]
        col_width.append(len(max(columns, key=len)))

    separator = "-+-".join('-' * n for n in col_width)

    for i, row in enumerate(range(rows)):
        if i == 1 and header_separator:
            print(separator)

        result = []
        for col in range(cols):
            item = data[row][col].rjust(col_width[col])
            result.append(item)

        print(cell_sep.join(result))
```

Добавляем в `Customer` метод:

```
    def values(self):
        return self.get_name(), self.get_address(), self.get_telephone(), \
               self.get_email(), self.mailList(),self.get_number()
```

И итог:

```
def main():
    customer = Customer('Josh', 'Long st, Dallas TX', '555-987-1549','adsf@asd.com','Y','1153')
    customer1 = Customer('Djon', 'Long st, Dallas TX', '555-987-1549','adsf@asd.com','Y','1153')
    customer2 = Customer('Ser', 'Long st, Dallas TX', '555-987-1549','adsf@asd.com','Y','1153')

    table_data = [
        ['NAME', 'ADDRESS', 'TELEPHONE', 'EMAIL', 'MAIL', 'NUMBER'],
        customer.values(),
        customer1.values(),
        customer2.values(),
    ]

    print_pretty_table(table_data)
```

Результат:

```
NAME |            ADDRESS |    TELEPHONE |        EMAIL |                MAIL | NUMBER
-----+--------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+-------
Josh | Long st, Dallas TX | 555-987-1549 | adsf@asd.com | On the mailing list |   1153
Djon | Long st, Dallas TX | 555-987-1549 | adsf@asd.com | On the mailing list |   1153
 Ser | Long st, Dallas TX | 555-987-1549 | adsf@asd.com | On the mailing list |   1153
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
...

def main():
    customer = Customer('Josh', 'Long st, Dallas TX',\
                                 '555-987-1549','adsf@asd.com','Y','1153').__str__().split("\n")
    customer1 = Customer('Djon', 'Long st, Dallas TX',\
                                 '555-987-1549','adsf@asd.com','Y','1153').__str__().split("\n")
    customer2 = Customer('Ser', 'Long st, Dallas TX',\
                                 '555-987-1549','adsf@asd.com','Y','1153').__str__().split("\n")    
    myList = []
    myList.append(customer)
    myList.append(customer1)
    myList.append(customer2)

    lenColumn = len(myList)  # 3
    num = lenColumn//3 if lenColumn%3==0 else lenColumn//3 + 1

    lenRow = len(myList[0])  # 7
    for i in range(num):
        for j in range(lenRow-1):
            print("{:30} {:30} {:30}".format(myList[i][j+1], myList[i+1][j+1], myList[i+2][j+1]))

main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]