# Сортировка словаря по значению

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, dict

Требутеся отсортировать `Dict` по значению `counter`
Мой код ошибок не выдает, просто не выполняет задуманной функции.

```
import re, requests

url_input = input("Enter url: ")

url_checked = re.findall(r'https?://\S+', url_input)[0] # берем первый элемент

if url_input != url_checked: # проверка валидности ссылки
    print("Entered url is invalid")
else:
    pass

response = requests.get(str(url_checked)) # запрос на введенную ссылку

result = re.findall(r'/[A-Za-z.]+/', response.text) # фильтрация ссылок

result.sort() # сортировка по алфавиту

def count_words(List):
    Dict = {}
    for word  in List:
        if word in Dict:
            Dict[word] += 1
        else:
            Dict[word] = 1

    for word, counter in Dict.items():
        Dict.update({word : counter})

    for word, counter in Dict.items():
        sorted(Dict.items(), key = lambda Dict: Dict[1])
        print(f"{word} matches {counter} times")

count_words(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В прошлом вопрос [я предлагал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1220904/201445) использовать `Counter`. Сейчас снова предлагаю

В `Counter` можно вывести слова, в порядке убывания через метод `most_common`.

Весь код:

```
from collections import Counter
...

def count_words(items):
    for word, counter in Counter(items).most_common():
        print(f"{word} matches {counter} times")
```

Comment: да, я использовал ваш вариант, но почему то поменял на этот. работает, спасибо

Comment: @Lcashe, пожалуйста :) Проголосуйте и примите ответ :)

Comment: через 3 минуты смогу принять ответ

Comment: @Lcashe уже прошол час, почему не приняли?

Comment: простите, уже принял

Comment: @Danis, не нужно такого контроля :D

Comment: @Lcashe, думаю, он просто пошутил :)

Comment: я просто видел ответ с комментарием "приму через 5 минут" но вопросу и ответу было несколько дней

Comment: @Danis, бывает :) У меня были ответы, про которые я давно забыл, а их принимали через несколько лет. Из недавнего это ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/984682/201445 принял автор ответ 09/12/2020. Скорее всего, ему ответ уже не нужен был и он забил на стек, а когда вернулся увидел уведомление о моем ответе и принял его